# Add only certain fields to array after sql query

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add only Items 1 to 5 to `$records` (Item 6 is used for something else). The code below will add all six items. How to add only the first five?

```
$TheQuery="SELECT Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6 FROM MyTable";
$result = $link->query($TheQuery);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $records[]=$row;
}
```

Comment: In that code your not adding nothing to anywhere, you're selecting data from your database. So, you don't even need to put the Item6 there, you can simply have: "$TheQuery="SELECT Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5 FROM MyTable";"

Comment: The $row results are stored in `$records`, thats what I mean by "add". However I don't want Item6 to be in `$records`, but I do want it to be present in the query, since I use it for another task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [array-slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $records[] = array_slice($row, 0, 5);
}
```

Also you can use `array_filter` ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)):

```
$keys = array("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $records[] = array_filter($row, function ($key) use ($keys ) {
        return in_array($key, $keys); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}
```

Comment: Right, the edited version using `array_filter` is working too. Going in the same direction @jameson pointed out: rest in the keys rather than the order of the items. Much more reliable. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use the column names rather than indexes in case you change the order of the query at sometime in the future,

You could use array_map like this:

$records[] = array_map(function($r){return [$r['item1'],$r['item2']... Etc];},$row);

Then you can always add/change columns if you need to in the future
(Forgive the formatting, I'm on my phone)

Comment: I'll give it a try. In its present form (after minimum adaptation to my real code) I'm getting an array in each spot of `$records` instead of the values. I will try latter to make it work, since it's a nice approach. Thanks!

Comment: Ahhh sorry I thought that was what you were after, a multidimensional array with an entry for each row

Comment: Mind you, we missed the simplest solution, just to say $records[]=$row[item1];$records[]=$row[item2];. But that's not exactly sexy is it